# Creating a Javascript 2d String array without length limit

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create a 2 dimensional string array in javascript that will allow an unlimited length in the first dimension, but a limited or unlimited length in the second dimension. The first dimension will need to be able to take in a string as a way to store and access the array. So let's say you have type and fieldNumber as the 2 dimensions. I would like to be able to store the array as such:

```
array[type][fieldNum] = value;
```

And type has to be able to be String.

I've been searching around, but all I found were either create a 1 dimension String array, create a 2 dimension array with row and col limits, and I couldn't find anywhere that allows me to do what I specified. Can anyone help out?

Comment: Did you try it with your code? If so, what problem are you having?

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare a multi dimensional array in javascript. But you can put an array in an array.

```
var myArray = [];
myArray.push([]);

myArray[0][1] = 'test';
```

So in your case, you must handle when you try to reach an empty index in your array (and fill this index with an empty array).

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to be able to store the array as such:

`array[type][fieldNum] = value;`

What about this ? (using object)

```
 var a ={};
 a[type]= {};
 a[type][fieldname]=someValue;
```

so :

```
  var a ={};
  a["john"]={};
  a["john"]["age"]=40;
  a["paul"]={};
  a["paul"]["age"]=70;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. this is no array, its an object when using strings as identifiers.
2. Objects/Arrays in Javascript are of unlimited length by default.

   ```
   object = {};
   //define 2nd dimension
   object["name"] = {};

   //enter stuff
   object["name"]["id"] = 5;
   ```